# Как изменить формат даты?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такая строка

```
INSERT INTO BUYINGS_DETAILS (
  ORDER_ID, ORDER_DATE, SUPPLIER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, UNITCOST
)
VALUES (
  304, date '9-JUN-2011', 1, 59, 20, 0.84
);
```

Нужно изменить с 9-JUN-2011 на 2011-06-09. Дело в том что таких строк более 100к и в каждой разная дата. Через регулярные выражения не получилось.

Comment: покажите Ваш regex

Comment: (\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+) и замена \4.\3\1

Comment: С одного захода думаю не получится. Но сперва можно пройтись этой регуляркой `/date '(\d{1})-([A-Z]{3})-(\d{4})'/gm` с заменой на $3-$2-0$1, затем поменять все строки у которых две цифры в числе, а потом заменить месяцы из слов на их цифровое значение с помощью простой замены строки.

Comment: Ничего не найдено(

Comment: Добавьте программный код если есть, каким образом запускаете регулярку вообще? В чем?

Comment: notepad++ использую

Comment: полагаю что для Notepad++ достаточно только то что ищется указать, без флагов и прочих спец. элементов: `date '(\d{1})-([A-Z]{3})-(\d{4})'`

Comment: Так работает. Но с заменой беда. Поиск работал и (\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+), но не работала замена

Comment: У меня Notepad'a нет, так что вряд ли смогу помочь. Смотрите документацию программы, синтаксис для выполнения замены

Answer (score 1):

Решение не универсальное, однако, в качестве варианта можно обернуть дату в штатную или собственную хранимую функцию. Если вы имеете дело с MySQL, можно вместо даты '9-JUN-2011' подставить в запрос MySQL-функцию `STR_TO_DATE()`, которая преобразует строку в дату по формату, заданному во втором аргументе функции

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9-JUN-2011', '%d-%b-%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('9-JUN-2011', '%d-%b-%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2011-06-09                            |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Тогда можно заменить выражение `('\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4}')` на `STR_TO_DATE(\1, '%d-%b-%Y')`. В случае другой базы данных следует поискать аналог функции `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:
поиск (\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)
замена \3-\2-\1

Comment: И такая замена заменяет `JUN` на `06` ?